# Moving from Windows Server 2012 to windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-server-2012

I have currently provisioned a workstation desktop as a server. I run Windows Server 2012 for running a few of my web apps and doing database work. While I have no complaints on Windows Server 2012, I miss the desktop features like audio, using high resolution graphics and sleep (WOL) for saving energy when the system is idle.

Can I switch to windows 8? When I tried this, there appears to be no way but a complete reinstall. Is there a way to keep my programs and data and just move the OS from Windows Server 2012 to Windows 8?

Comment: You can enable these features on Windows Server. I am currently using Server 2008 R2 as a desktop.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the desktop niceties like audio, etc., then perhaps instead of up/down/side-grading your OS, instead enable the "Desktop Experience" features of Server (2012), which will make it behave (more) like a desktop/workstation OS.

To enable it in Server 2012:

- Open **Server Manager** and click the **Add roles and features** link.
- In the right panel scroll all the way down to **Roles and Features**, click the **Tasks** drop-down and choose **Add Roles and Features**.
- Navigate through the wizard.
- When asked, select **Role-based or feature-based installation**.
- Pick the (local) server.
- Skip the **Roles** page, as we're enabling a *feature*.
- At the **Select Features** page, expand **User Interfaces and Infrastructure**
- Check-mark the **Desktop Experience** option.
- Finish the wizard, rebooting if necessary.

More info [here](http://www.win2012workstation.com/desktop-experience/).

Answer (score 2):

No there is no "upgrade" path from 2012 to Windows 8 (nor vice-versa), you must reinstall to switch OS's.

Answer (score 2):

The best method would be to backup all of your data and do a fresh install of Windows 8. If you download the Windows 8 ISO on a Windows 7 computer you will be able to purchase the cheaper upgrade version. After you have installed Windows 8 you will be able to restore your files.

The reason being that Windows Server 2012 is quite different to Windows 8 in terms of available software. As far as I know there is no direct upgrade route. If you are running it as a fully fledged server you will most certainly run into a few problems trying to get the same setup going on Windows 8.

Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 both serve two different purposes so I don't think Microsoft has any reason to great a direct upgrade route.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to install Windows Easy transfer, if it's not included in server, and at least migrate your settings and profile. I don't believe there is a way to 'upgrade' from server to workstation and keep installed applications in tact.

If you have the extra hard drive space for a second partition you could dual boot and run both. Windows 7 Ultimate/Enterprise has a boot-able virtual hard disk that can run alongside Server 08, so they might have a similar function for 8 and 2012 and not even need the seperate partition?

Otherwise Sam has it right with doing a good backup on your data, and a fresh install.

Comment: Windows Easy Transfer is not included with Windows Server 2012.